# emulator show only one marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to add multiple markers on Google map but emulator shows only one marker!
Here is my code section:
I'm getting values of lat and lng from database

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
ArrayList<LatLng> marker;
ArrayList<LatLng> markers;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    // Initializing 
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    marker = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    markers = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
     findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();      

    if(map!=null){

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     


        long time = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
       String Timestemp = Timestemp();
        int locationCount =locationCount() ;


         double Latt = Lat();
         double Lngg = Lng();

             markers.add(new LatLng(Latt, Lngg));               

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(new LatLng(Latt, Lngg));
                if(markers.size()>=1){

                    for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++)
                     {
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.
                         defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }
                options.title(time+"");         
                options.snippet(Timestemp+" last updated");
                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

    }
    }
}






 public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) 
    {
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

     String line = null;
     try {
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
     } 
     catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     finally {
      try {
       is.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
     return sb.toString();
    }

 public static double Lng()
 {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/Lng");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    }
 public static double Lat()
 {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/Lat");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    }

 public static int locationCount()
 {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/locationCount");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             return 0;
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return 0;
     }

    } 

         public static String Timestemp()
 {
    try
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();

        //Connect to the server
        HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:51220/Service1.svc/Timestemp");
      //Get the response
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
         InputStream stream=httpEntity.getContent();

         //Convert the stream to readable format
            String result= convertStreamToString(stream);

            if(result.charAt(1)=='1')
            {
             return "1";
            }
            else
            {
             return "0";
            }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
      return "0";
     }

    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your code doesn't work as excepted because you're doing network operations on the main thread and then catching all exceptions so actually what is happening is something like this...

1. Network operation throws `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.
2. `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is caught and ignored by your `catch (Exception e)` code block.
3. Network methods always `return 0` from the catch block.

Some good practices for Android development to consider:

1. Never do network operations on the main thread.
2. Never catch `Exception`.
3. Handle exceptions properly with logging and sensible errors to the user where necessary, this will also help you debug errors.

Comment: there is no any error even showing map but i want multiple markers it shows only one marker :(

Comment: without network operations how do i get values from database through web service ??